# Is it possible to configure a subdomain using Firebase if the domain is being hosted somewhere else?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Is it possible to configure a subdomain using Firebase if the domain is being hosted somewhere else?
I'd really like to configure landing pages to my customer's accounts without digging too far into it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just go to hosting and click add custom domain, then enter the full subdomain (example: sub.example.com, NOT: sub, NOT: example.com). Don't include any protocols such as HTTP or HTTPS, then click continue. Verify your ownership of that domain by opening your domain registrar, and adding the two A records you see there. The Name/Host/Alias field in your domain registrar should be the subdomain, the Record Type field should be A, and the Value field should be the 2 IP addresses listed in the firebase console.